# How to interpret autocorrelation plot?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, stationarity, acf-pacf

I'm having trouble making sense out of this ACF plot

According to an ADF test, the series is definitely stationary. Also, the presence of autocorrelation is explained by the order 1 lag, as evidenced by the pacf, however the peak around 65 confuses me, how should I interpret it? The pacf does indicate there is something happening around the order 60 lag

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you post the data and I will try and help ..

Comment: Thank you Irish, let me clean some stuff first and I'll share :)

Comment: and your data is where ?

Comment: that's quite the passive aggressive remark @IrishStat, what method do you prefer to share the data?

Comment: You can send it to my email address. if you wish

Comment: or attach it your post ...or ..

Answer (score 1):

This looks like ARIMA(1,1,0) to me: PACF cuts off at lag 2, which suggests AR(2), but ACF at lag 1 is close to 1, which suggests differencing.

If you're positive that it's stationary, then AR(2) would be another choice.

Comment: I'm positive about stationary behavior (ADF and visual) and I'm also sure a high order lag is relevant, that's why the 'little hill' around 60 is important. Imagine a process that repeats every two months. I believe ARIMA(1,1,0) sounds like I could be missing something, SARIMAX maybe?

Comment: A little hill is an artifact of either AR(2) with second lag negative or combo of differencing and a lag, in my opinion. I wouldn't rush to interpret it as seasonality

Comment: What is the nature of series?

Comment: financial data, difference between an estimation and its moving average

Comment: What is the width of moving average window? Is it monthly? Is it business or calendar days?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81782/discussion-between-yuca-and-aksakal).